# Glue connector to metal/resin case

Tags: battery-charging, connector, enclosure, glue

Want to use this type of connector https://cletk.en.alibaba.com/product/60724170404-804809515/Usb_Cable_Charger_Magnetic_Dc_Power_Cable_Connectors_Power_Adapter.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.41413.12.141371b2bIt95e as a charging connector for my small battery-powered product. What would be the best way to fix it in my cases? I use two types of cases, one is CNC aluminum and the other is 3D printed resin. Thinking of some type of glue or epoxy, but do you have any specific recommendations that would work well in the long term? Temperature can vary from 0* C to 80* C (for short periods of time). No significant mechanical resistance required, besides what you'd normally expect when handling the product.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks to me like it is meant to be mounted on a PCB. Then you only have the problem of mounting the PCB in the case.

Answer (score 1):

Epoxy is not the best for smooth walled metal but excellent for FR4 which is also epoxy. The best I have found for this is high VOC Polyurethane subfloor adhesive ,now replaced with slow drying low VOC subfloor adhesive. Excellent bonding and strain relief and inexpensive XL  in tubes.